# Swipe to delete cell Height is decrease every time in xamarin ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, swipe

I am new to iOS. I am creating TableView with swipe to delete the cell. But When I swipe every time the cell height is decrease. I am using iOS 10. The below code I have used.

**Code :**

```
class AppointmentSourceClass : UITableViewSource
    {
        List<AppointmentItem> appointments;

        public AppointmentSourceClass(List<AppointmentItem> appointments)
        {
            this.appointments = appointments;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            ApointListCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(ApointListCell.Key) as ApointListCell ?? ApointListCell.Create();
            var item = appointments[indexPath.Row];

            cell.BindData(item);

            cell.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
            cell.Layer.CornerRadius = 5.0f;
            cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
            cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

            return cell;
        }

        public override void CommitEditingStyle(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCellEditingStyle editingStyle, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            switch (editingStyle)
            {
                case UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete:
                    appointments.RemoveAt(indexPath.Row);
                    tableView.DeleteRows(new NSIndexPath[] { indexPath},UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
                    break;
                case UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None:
                    break;
            }
        }

        public override bool CanEditRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override string TitleForDeleteConfirmation(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return "Trash ( ";
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return appointments.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

Before Swipe Image :

[image]

After Swipe Image :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

In the TableCell I have use below code to seperate the two tableCell and make space between them. If i remove the code then it working fine.

```
public override CoreGraphics.CGRect Frame
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Frame;
            }
            set
            {
                value.Y += 4;
                value.Height -= 2 * 4;
                base.Frame = value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: And that is why so important to share the complete solution and not just pieces of code :-)